# ASP.NET MVC Routing, "bin" as a route parameter value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, special-folders, bin

We are developing an English-Turkish dictionary website.

"Bin" means "Thousand" in Turkish. So when a user asks for http://tureng.com/search/bin we should show her the meaning of "Bin" in English. However, since /bin is a special directory, she got a 404.

Any ideas to solve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing /bin from IIS 7 hiddenSegments, solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx
Haven't tested it with "Bin" in path, but there is a good chance it will work.